# React Hooks: useEffect set with a dependency renders initial image instead of set image

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, multer, use-effect

I am using the React Hook [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) to help set a default image for an image loading component (it loads a users avatar for their profile page), however because the nature of the layout system of [Semantic-UI-React](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/docs/src/layouts/HomepageLayout.js) there seems to be a re-rendering happening when we go from mobile to desktop.

But what I am not understanding is my `setState` has its default image changed after the image gets uploaded. i.e. file path gets set to a state variable so why does it change?

This is my component:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { Card, Icon, Image, Segment, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import axios from 'axios';

function ImageUploader() {

  var [userAvatar, setUserAvatar] = useState(
    require('../../assests/profile-avatars/placeholder.jpg') /* Setting default avatar */
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setUserAvatar(userAvatar);
  }, [userAvatar]);

  function fileUploader(e) {
    e.persist();

    var imageFormObj = new FormData();
    console.log('e.target.files[0 ', e.target.files[0]);

    imageFormObj.append('imageName', 'multer-image-' + Date.now());
    imageFormObj.append('imageData', e.target.files[0]);

    axios
      .post(`/users/uploadmulter`, imageFormObj)
      .then(data => {
        if (data.status === 200) {
          console.log('data ', data);
          var { path } = data.data;

          setUserAvatar('../../' + path);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert('Error while uploading image using multer');
      });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Segment>
        <Card fluid>
          <Image src={userAvatar} alt="upload-image" />
          <Segment>
            <Form encType="multipart/form-data">
              <Form.Field>
                <input
                  placeholder="Name of image"
                  className="process__upload-btn"
                  type="file"
                  content="Edit your Avatar!"
                  onChange={e => fileUploader(e)}
                  name="avatar"
                />
              </Form.Field>
            </Form>
          </Segment>
          <Card.Content>
            <Card.Header>Charly</Card.Header>
            <Card.Meta>
              <span className="date">Joined in 2015</span>
            </Card.Meta>
            <Card.Description>Charly</Card.Description>
          </Card.Content>
          <Card.Content extra>
            <a>
              <Icon name="user" />
              22 Friends
            </a>
          </Card.Content>
        </Card>
      </Segment>
    </>
  );
}

export default ImageUploader;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
var [userAvatar, setUserAvatar] = useState(
    require('../../assests/profile-avatars/placeholder.jpg') /* Setting default avatar */
);
```

You can just specify path to the placeholder, there is no need to require it.

```
var [userAvatar, setUserAvatar] = useState('../../assests/profile-avatars/placeholder.jpg');
```

It doesn't seem it's a right place to use `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setUserAvatar(userAvatar);
}, [userAvatar]);
```

This code doesn't do anything useful. To update a state value you can call `setUserAvatar` directly (like you do in `fileUploader`):

```
setUserAvatar(userAvatar);
```

Try to remove `useEffect` and see how it goes.

[Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)